# import everything from a module except a few methods (Fortran)

Tags: import, module, fortran

I want to import everything in ISO_FORTRAN_ENV except for NUMERIC_STORAGE_SIZE, how can I do that?

Comment: Why?  Are you trying to avoid a warning that involves NUMERIC_STORAGE_SIZE?

Comment: @evets likely yes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50869826/how-to-specify-mpif90-to-compile-with-64-bits-integer

Answer (score 1):

Strictly you can't.

What you can do is rename `NUMERIC_STORAGE_SIZE` to something that is unlikely to be a problem for you in the scope of the USE statement.

```
USE :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, something_unlikely_to_be_a_problem => NUMERIC_STORAGE_SIZE
```

However, because ISO_FORTRAN_ENV is an intrinsic module that is not under your control, a common style recommendation is to go the other way - explicitly list the entities from that module in an only clause that you need to access.  This avoids problems with future revisions of that module, either by updates to the standard or by the vendor of you Fortran processor, introducing identifiers that clash with existing local identifiers in the scope of the use statement.

Comment: There is a ´NON_INTRINSIC´ attribute, isn't there?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Since Fortran 2003, you can specify `NON_INTRINSIC` after `USE` (with a `,` in between) in the same way that you specify `INTRINSIC` after it.  However, I am not sure that's an "attribute" in Fortran lore: while, under "Terms and definitions", "attribute" is defined as "property of an entity that determines its uses", the section of the standard on "Attribute declarations and specifications" only considers attributes in relation to data objects, which I understand modules are not.  And objects can have the (meaning-related) `INTRINSIC` attribute, but not `NON_INTRINSIC`.

Comment: But you can specify it for other entity, no? Iike prodedures or variables in an import statement?